# Typescript: Executor Task Interface

Tags: typescript

Estoy tratando de hacer una interfaz tal que alguna variable, por ejemplo, args, corresponda a los argumentos de una función dada.

```
export interface ExecutorTask<T extends any[]> {
  args: T;
  thisValue: Object;
  fn: (...args: T) => any;
}
```

Pero tengo este error:

```
Typescript
A rest parameter must be of an array type.
```

Cualquier ayuda sería muy apreciada. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que, por una limitación de Typescript, no te detecta la clase genérica T como un array, tienes que declarar explícitamente un tipo array para ese parámetro. Hay incluso una tarea abierta en el repositorio oficial de Typescript pidiendo que se admita esta declaración, pero de momento [no se le ha prestado atención](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2328). Por tanto, la única solución que hay es cambiar tu código a:

```
export interface ExecutorTask<any[]> {
  args: any[];
  thisValue: Object;
  fn: (...args: any[]) => any;
}
```